# How to generate a TOC without an actual document?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a PowerPoint presentation to be ready next week for an exam. As I am not very familiar to the TeXnical way to create a presentation, I don't want to rewrite it in TeX. I have the requirement to create a handout for the presentation. The handout is required to have an outline of the presentation.

Is there any package to create a TOC in a LaTeX document that has no relationship to the sections and chapters of the document itself? I need something where I can create an outline like

> 1. Foo
>
>    - A
>    - B
>    - C
> 2. Bar
>
>    - D
>    - E
>    - F
> 3. Baz
>
>    - G
>    - H

Comment: Just use list environments? If you need something more involved, please give more details.

Comment: @Caramdir I like the LaTeX formatting of TOCs more than the formatting of plain lists. Also, I want to have the same style as a usual TOC.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Your example doesn't really look like a LaTeX ToC (bullet points?)

Comment: @FUZxxl: you should have mentioned the required layout in your question! Anyway, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo It's just, that I like the default layout of LaTeX' TOCs. I am curious, whether there is any package, that allows the user to write custom TOCs using this formatting.

Comment: @FUZxxl: there's no need for any special package; see the third example in my answer.

Comment: I edited the title to be a bit more specific, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the standard `enumerate` and `itemize` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Foo
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
  \end{itemize}
  \item Bar
  \begin{itemize}
    \item D
    \item E
    \item F
  \end{itemize}
  \item Baz
  \begin{itemize}
    \item G
    \item H
    \item I
  \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Since the format required is the one of a legal list, you can use the `enumerate` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{legal}
  \item Foo
  \begin{legal}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
  \end{legal}
  \item Bar
  \begin{legal}
    \item D
    \item E
    \item F
  \end{legal}
  \item Baz
  \begin{legal}
    \item G
    \item H
    \item I
  \end{legal}
\end{legal}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: another option would be to create a "dummy" document with only the sectional units and let `\tableofcontents` generate the ToC with its standard layout; the correct page numbering can be obtained through a command that sets the page counter (the example requires two compilations):

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand\MyCmd[1]{\mbox{}\clearpage\setcounter{page}{#1}}

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents
\MyCmd{3}
\chapter{Foo}
\MyCmd{3}
\section{A}
\MyCmd{4}
\section{B}
\MyCmd{8}
\section{C}
\MyCmd{12}
\chapter{Bar}
\MyCmd{16}
\section{D}
\MyCmd{18}
\section{E}
\MyCmd{20}
\section{F}
\MyCmd{22}
\chapter{Baz}
\MyCmd{23}
\section{G}
\MyCmd{25}
\section{H}
\MyCmd{27}
\section{I}

\end{document}
```

[image]