# Rendering only the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Strange question, but I wanted to know if its possible to render only the table of contents and not the associated body of text below. Is there a suppression command that means that a section is processed but not drawn?

Comment: And Welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I would have to do that. I just wondered if there were any other options.

Comment: [See also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19548/45342)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by preparing a `printtoc.tex` file

```
\documentclass{book} % use the same class
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % if you use babel (same options!)
%% Add other packages that act on the page shape
%% you load in the main file

\begin{document}
\frontmatter % if you use book or similar class
%\setcounter{page}{3} % if the original toc starts page iii

\chapter{\contentsname}

\makeatletter
\input{thesis.toc}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

where I suppose that `thesis.tex` is the name of your main file.

Answer (score 2):

If you put your text in separate files and `\include` them in a master file then you can use `\includeonly` to generate just a table of contents.